# Looping over JSON data with PHP and jQuery, decrement on click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

So I'm building an area on my homepage that displays a tip.  The tip changes everyday and shows the correesponding tip from the JSON using PHP.

```
    // SET LANGUAGE 
    $lang = "english";
    $config = 'config-english.php';
    if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language'] == 'spanish')
    {
        $lang = 'spanish';
        $config = 'config-spanish.php';
    }
```

I also added a "View Previous Tip" below it.  There is a language picker at the top so I'm using PHP to change the language variable by checking the $_GET variable and JSON to pull in the tips info.  I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to index over the json data and use that index to compare the current date to the corresponding tip date and show previous day's tip.

I'm thinking of rewriting it using ajax.  I tried $.each() but it doesn't provide enough control over the index.  Here I'm using the jQuery for loop so specify the array, then specify a key:value.

Does jQuery index the key:value items by default so I can do something like this:

```
 $("btn").prev().show(item[i]-1);
```

JSON (external doc):

```
    {
    "3/12": "Tip number 1.",
    "3/24": "Tip number 2.",
    "3/25": "Tip number 3",
     }
```

PHP pulls in the json (from external page and displays the tip corresponding to today's date)

```
$tipsjson = file_get_contents("scripts/tips-$lang.json");
$y = json_decode($tipsjson, true);
$day = date('n/d');
$current_tip =  array_search($day,array_keys($y));
echo $y[$day];
```

jQuery - Passing in the JSON variable created in the PHP script and loops over the json (this is where I'm struggling)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var tips = <?php echo $tipsjson; ?>;
var current_tip = <?php echo current_tip; ?>;
    for ( var i=0; i < tips.length; i++ )
    {
    var item = tips;
    console.log(tips);
    }

     $('.previous').on('click', function() 
    {
    // Decrement over the index and show previous json item when clicked                        
    });

}); // doc.ready
```

Array structure of $y

```
Array
(
[3/13] => Tip number 1.
[3/24] => Tip number 2.
[3/25] => Tip number 3.
)
```

Comment: Can you post the array structure of $y?

Comment: use a counter inside of $.each and increment it accordingly, use it as you need?